# confusion using np.array and purpose of double round brackets ((

Tags: python, numpy

```
  features = np.array(([0.1,0.5,0.2],
                       [0.2,0.3,0.1],
                       [0.7,0.4,0.2],
                       [0.1,0.4,0.3]))
```

I have failed to understand what is the purpose of double round brackets **"(("** here . Although this is functional, however I remove a single round bracket **"("** bracket like below

```
    features = np.array([0.1,0.5,0.2],
                        [0.2,0.3,0.1],
                        [0.7,0.4,0.2],
                        [0.1,0.4,0.3])
```

This gives me the following error

```
File "C:\Users\XPS\PycharmProjects\MyProject1\bleed3.py", line 29, in <module>
features = np.array([0.1,0.5,0.2],
TypeError: array() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Clarification: Thanks everyone for your response. I had all the pieces of the puzzles, as pointed out by "Karl Knechtel",  but just some how couldn't put it together. After reading the responses I understood the issue, Its clear now.

I also googles before posting.

thanks again

Comment: It is not "double round brackets". The inner parentheses bundle up the lists, so that they are a single argument, and the outer parentheses as making the function call. "This gives me the following error" Okay, so **what don't you understand** about the error? For example, do you know what a `TypeError` is? Do you know what `positional arguments` are? I recommend to study a general Python tutorial first and make sure you are comfortable with the fundamentals, before trying to use Numpy. Anyway, please read [ask] and try to **ask a question** when posting.

Comment: `fun(arg)` is a function call.  `(1,2,3)` is a tuple. `[1,2,3]` is a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner parens are a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences). A tuple is like a list, but it is immutable.

So your example is equivalent to this:

```
  features = np.array([[0.1,0.5,0.2],
                       [0.2,0.3,0.1],
                       [0.7,0.4,0.2],
                       [0.1,0.4,0.3]])
```

Which creates a 2D array.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Now I got it . much obliged.